# Append & add text to a file

Tags: text, append

I have the following code.  yes I have many lines remed out for now as I am testing the code.

```
Actual text from file: forecast= Mostly cloudy and cooler. Precipitation ending with in 6 hours. Windy with possible wind shift to the W NW or N.
```

When I run the file, it looks for the periods to split the text into 5 different variables.
forecast1, forecast2, forecast3, forecast4, forecast5.
It properly splits the file, as shown by the not needed print commands.
The problem I have it properly amending each new value the the existing text file realtimegauges.txt.
I get the following placed in the text file:
forecast1=Mostly cloudy and cooler. Precipitation ending with in 6 hours. Windy with possible wind shift to the W NW or N.
forecast2=Mostly coudy and coolerfoecast3=precipitationending in 6 hours.
Its not putting each new (forecastX) variable on its own line.

```
# safely open the text file we created and search for a string
with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "forecast=" in line:
            str = (line)
            
            
            
           
forecast1= (str.rsplit('=',1)[1])
forecast2= (forecast1.rsplit('.',5)[0])
try:forecast3= (forecast1.rsplit('.',5)[1])
except  IndexError:
        forecast3 = ('')
try:forecast4= (forecast1.rsplit('.',5)[2])
except  IndexError:
        forecast4 = ('')
try:forecast5= (forecast1.rsplit('.',5)[3])
except  IndexError:
        forecast5 = ('')
print (forecast1)
with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:
    f.write('forecast1=' + forecast1)
print (forecast2)
with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:
    f.write('forecast2=' + forecast2)
print (forecast3)
with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:
    f.write('forecast3=' + forecast3)
    f.close()
print (forecast4)
print (forecast5)

#with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:
 #   f.write('forecast1=' + forecast1)
  #  f.close()
#with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:
 #   f.write('forecast2=' + forecast2)
  #  f.close()
#with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:
 #   f.write('forecast3=' + forecast3)
  #  f.close()
#with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:
 #   f.write('forecast4=' + forecast4)
#with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt",'a') as f:    
 #   f.write('forecast5=' + forecast5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using print to file

```
with open("/home/admin/Documents/realtimegauges.txt","a") as f:
    print("forecast2=" + (forecast2) ,file=f)
    print ("forecast3=" + (forecast3) ,file=f)
    print ("forecast4=" + (forecast4) ,file=f)
    print ("forecast5=" + (forecast5) ,file=f)
```